# How can I add timer on canvas, surface view?

Tags: android, canvas, timer, android-studio

I'm using canvas to draw a ball moving in the screen, what happens is that when I emulate the application on my friend's phone, the ball moves slower than on my own phone. I'd like to know how I can use a delay or something, to control how many times/sec my app will draw on the screen, here is the code I'm using:

```html
public class rodando extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnTouchListener{

    OurView v;
    int x = 0,y = 0;
    Bitmap Ball;
    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rodando);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        v = new OurView(this);
        v.setOnTouchListener(this);
        ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ball);
        setContentView(v);

    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        v.resume();
    }

    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        v.pause();
    }


    public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable
    {


        Thread t = null;
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        boolean isItOK = false;



        public OurView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            holder = getHolder();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {


            while(isItOK == true)
            {
                Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();

                if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                {
                    continue;
                }

                c.drawBitmap(ball,x,y,null);
                x++;
                y++;

                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
         

            }
        }

        public void pause()
        {
            isItOK = false;
            while(true)
            {
                try{
                    t.join();
                }catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            t = null;
        }

        public void resume()
        {
            isItOK = true;
            t = new Thread(this);

            t.start();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_rodando, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        
return true;
        }
        
}
```

Comment: Isn't half your code missing?